# What exactly is in ubuntu-desktop?

Tags: package-management, metapackages

I'm also interested in its variants, like kubuntu-desktop. It appears to include GNOME (or KDE) and a bunch of other things. But it's quite large - is there a breakdown of what is included in ubuntu-desktop and exactly what those items are/do?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The ubuntu-desktop (and similar) packages are metapackages. That is, they contain no data (besides a small documentation file in the case of the *-desktop packages). But they depend on dozens of other packages that make up each of the Ubuntu flavors.

You can see a complete listing of each package's dependencies on packages.ubuntu.com. A [quick search](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=names&keywords=ubuntu-desktop) lists these metapackages.

- [ubuntu-desktop](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/ubuntu-desktop)
- [kubuntu-desktop](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/kubuntu-desktop)
- [xubuntu-desktop](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/xubuntu-desktop)
- [lubuntu-desktop](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/lubuntu-desktop)
- [edubuntu-desktop](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/edubuntu-desktop)
- [edubuntu-desktop-kde](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/edubuntu-desktop-kde)

A more detailed explanation of metapackages and a list of some more useful metapackages can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MetaPackages).

Answer (score 3):

[Too much to list here!](http://packages.ubuntu.com/lucid/ubuntu-desktop)

You can click through each package for a detailed description. Note these dependant packages have their own dependencies and some of those have even more.

Comment: http://packages.ubuntu.com is a great tool!